# Cant submit my button with form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I am trying to submit my button with a form. Im not trying to make my button submit the form. I want to be able to see my button value in the POST variable after the form submits. From my understanding all I need is to give my element a name and value. I should be able to see all the form variables once my form is submitted.

```
<input name='MC[]' type='text' size='51' placeholder='Enter In Question'>
<br/>
<input name='MC[]' type='button' value='Incorrect'>
<input name='MC[]' id='Options' size='40' placeholder='Enter In Option A'>
```

I'm new to this site not sure if I'm providing enough information but I simply want to submit this button inside a form and to be able to add the value of my button to a file. For some reason I cant see the button once the form is submitted. Are type button not sent to POST when submitted?

Note, I am able to see my other input elements. The type button one is the only one I cant see.

Comment: without submit type button you can't submit for (until you use jquery/javascript).Also with submit button also you can send some value

Comment: Do you want to submit "Incorrect" if the button is clicked or always?

Comment: Not sure what the purpose of your button is, but you could add a hidden input and keep your button there. `<input type="hidden" value="incorrect">`

Comment: Yes, Ill try that out. I still don't understand why a type button wont send, but I can easily get what I want with a hidden value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Javascript that fills in the value of a hidden input from the value of the button that was clicked.

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="answer" id="answer">
```

JS:

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[name='MC[]']").forEach(function(el) {
    el.addEventListener("click", function() {
        document.getElementById("answer").value = el.value;
    }
}
```

Then you'll be able to get the button's value in `$_POST['answer']`.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how buttons work... they perform an action, they don't get included in the post data. What you need is a checkbox, or a disabled input perhaps?

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to avoid using a checkbox and disabled input. I tried both of those ways already and they worked, but I didn't like how they looked so I was trying to use a button instead.I personally don't see how a button wouldn't send. An input element is an input element in my opinion. I would assume everything would send as long as I give them a name.

Comment: `An input element is an input element in my opinion.`
Very true!

Comment: You could always style a checkbox to look like a button? Or use a button that triggers an action to mutate a hidden input's value?

Comment: Yes, thank you. That completely eluded me. I forgot about hidden input's. Ill try that instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not provide an answer.